# Passing Data from Table Rows into an Object Literal with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here's an example table row from my table:

```
<tr class="formulaRow">
    <td>
              <input type="text" class="ingredient required" name="ingredient">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="amount required" name="amount">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="carrier required" name="carrier" max="100">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="kilo required" name="kilo">
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="tableDropDown" style="min-width: 100px;">
                <option value="other">The Manufacturer</option>
                <option value="me">Me</option>
         </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="packSize" type="number" disabled>
    </td>
</tr>

<button type="submit" class="analyze">Analyze</button>
```

I need to pass this data from each table row into the following javascript function to be further processed once it gets pushed into the "formula" array:

```
var addIngredient = function(ingredient, active, carrier, price, origin, packSize) {
    var ingredient = {
        ingredient: ingredient,
        active: active,
        carrier: carrier,
        price: price,
        origin: origin,
        packSize: packSize
    };

    state.formula.push(ingredient);

};
```

I'm trying to accomplish this task with the following jquery function:

```
$(".analyze").click(function() {
var ingredients = $(".formulaRow");
$("ingredients").each(function() {
    addIngredient($(":input"));
    }
}
```

However, this is not working.

It might also be important to note that the addIngredient function is stored on a separate javascript file called data-model.js, whereas the jquery function is stored in a file called interactions.js that both load in the head of the html page.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ingredients = $(".formulaRow");
```

is grabbing all your "tr" elements with class "formulaRow". On each row you have inputs and a select. You want the values of those form elements. I would change your addIngredient function to:

```
var addIngredient = function($row) {
    var ingredient = {};
    $row.find('input, select').each(function(){
       ingredient[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
         //^^this is grabbing the attribute off the html element
         //i.e. ingredient["amount"]
    });

    state.formula.push(ingredient);

};
```

to be called like:

```
var $ingredients = $(".formulaRow");
$ingredients.each(function() {
    addIngredient($(this));
}
```

however you'll want to add "name" attributes to your select element and the input.packSize for this to work.